# Can I convert liquid foam or bubbles to point cloud and use it inside geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, fluid-simulation

Can I convert liquid foam or bubbles to point cloud and use it inside geometry nodes ?

I'm trying to spread objects on liquid object , and I would like these scattered objects look like they are stick to the surface , normal scattering changing points position each frame[image: screenshut of my scene]
Thanks guys